# Detect Fields that do not have ID attribute using grep and regex

Tags: regex, perl, grep

Need to find the following patern in a file using grep and regular expression :-

```
        $form->AddFields({
            type => 'hidden',
            name => 'xyz',
            value => 0,
        });
```

i think we nee to use multi line grep for this.
Can anyone help please.?

Comment: Provide your input file also

Comment: Also, how permissive do you want the regex to be? Should it allow different amounts of whitespace? Should it still work if `type`, `name` and `value` are in a different order? Or if `type` is `visible`, or `$type`, etc?

Comment: yes it should allow diffrent amount of white spaces. type, name and value can be in different order. and the value of type, name and value field can be different.

Comment: Are you willing to do this with a script instead of `grep` from the command line?

Comment: Yes, a script might also help. But i want to find out that it can be done via grep or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using awk:

```
awk '{ printf /id =>/? FS: $0 RS}' RS='});' file
```

#### Input:

```
$form->AddFields({
    id => 2048
    type => 'hidden',
    name => 'xyz',
    value => 0,
});

$form->AddFields({
    type => 'hidden',
    name => 'xyz',
    value => 0,
});

$form->AddFields({
    type => 'hidden',
    name => 'xyz',
    id => 1024,
    value => 0,
});
```

#### Output:

```
$form->AddFields({
    type => 'hidden',
    name => 'xyz',
    value => 0,
});
```

Comment: I like this solution much better than my own.

Comment: This is perfect.! solves the problem i was looking for.

Comment: @KasiyA , i found a problem with this command. When i try to run this command to find this pattern across a set of files. It is also listing contents of the file which do not have any form field at all.! 
How do i avoid this.?

Comment: For the input that you mentioned it is giving the desirable output.
But if i run this command :- 

awk '{ printf /id =>/? FS: $0 RS}' RS='});' $file

The content of $file is :- "This is just a test input"

  The output is coming as :- "This is just a test input".
  I want to avoid this. It should only print when the file has a "AddField" function and the "id" attribute missing from it.
If the file does not have any "AddField" function at all, it should not print anything.

Comment: @sanketchatterjee try this `awk '/form->AddFields/,/\}\)\;/{ printf /id =>/? FS: $0 RS}' RS='});' <<<$file`. this will pints nothing but will works on example input in my answer if you change `<<<$file` to `file`

Comment: Yes, this is working. :)  I want to capture the output into a variable so that I can do future processing with my Perl code. I am trying to use system() for that,but its not working. Should i use any other function for this purpose.?

Comment: @sanketchatterjee I'm not perl expert but if you want to save the output of `awk` use that inside command-substitution(`$(...)`) like `variable=$(awk ...)` and then if you type `echo "$variable"` you will see the output of that awk processed. Thanks. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

It's not a grep statement, but might want to try this Perl script (this assumes you're feeding the input via STDIN).  It also assumes that you don't have any forms that are truncated within the input (forms that begin before the input start or end after the input ends), but there's ways to deal with those conditions if they are relevant to you.

```
use strict;
use warnings;


sub processRecord {
  my ($record) = @_;
  my $text = join("\n", @{$record});
  print "$text\n" unless $text =~ /ID\s*=>\s*/;
}


my $recordStart = qr/^\s*\$form\s*->\s*AddFields\s*\(\s*\{\s*/;
my $recordEnd = qr/\s*\}\s*\)\s*;\s*$/;
my @record;
my $inRecord = 0;
while (my $line=<>) {
  next unless $line =~ /\S/;
  chomp($line);
  $inRecord = 1 if $line =~ /$recordStart/;
  if ($line =~ /$recordEnd/) {
    push(@record, $line);
    processRecord(\@record);
    @record = ();
    $inRecord = 0;
    next;
  }
  push(@record, $line) if $inRecord;
}
```